# &optional BUFFER for other-buffer function does not work?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I need to switch to another buffer I have a key binding that will create a buffer called `"*Buffer List*"` from which I select the new buffer.

I need a command to switch between current buffer and the previous one. Except I don't want `"*Buffer List*"`. I looked up function definition for other-buffer:

```
(other-buffer &optional BUFFER VISIBLE-OK FRAME)

Return most recently selected buffer other than BUFFER...
```

so I tried using:

```
(other-buffer "*Buffer List*")
```

Now if in the new buffer I execute above code with `C-x C-e` it will echo `"*Buffer List*"`, instead of the initial buffer that I called `"*Buffer List*"` from. So `&optional BUFFER` does not seem to work the way I do it. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help: use backquotes `` around literals.

Comment: How about using some of these instead?  `M-x previous-buffer`; `M-x next-buffer`; `M-x switch-to-buffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BUFFER` must be a buffer object. To use the buffer name you would need to use:

```el
(other-buffer (get-buffer "*Buffer List*"))
```

Notice that when you *can* use a buffer's name as the argument, the documentation tends to name that argument `BUFFER-OR-NAME` (e.g. see the docstring for `get-buffer` itself), and to be explicit about the fact in the text.

If you see `BUFFER` as an argument, it likely requires the actual buffer object (as in this instance).

Comment: Thanks phils. I appreciate your response.